# Regex to replace anything not precceded a word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I want to replace string containing `b-` with `bst-`. The edge cases are 
`b-` should not be preceded by any letter.

input = "b-picker-wrap b-active bob-state-default .b-picker /b-pic";

output = "bst-picker-wrap bst-active bob-state-default .bst-picker /bst-pic";

Comment: You tried anything?

Comment: str.replace('b-', 'bst-');

Comment: `.replaceAll("\\bb-", "bst-")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```js
var input = "b-picker-wrap b-active bob-state-default .b-picker /b-pic",
    result = input.replace(/\bb-/g, "bst-");
    
console.log(result);
```

- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: @PrakashGupta, you're welcome